# error in dataset copy functions

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to copy one dataset to another dataset using copy funcitons

```
dsSave = dBindset.copy
```

but in these in dsSave all data were copied but only one cell data didn't copied..

what is the reason for this?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `AcceptChanges()` before you call the `Copy`.

```
dBindset.AcceptChanges()
dsSave = dBindset.copy()
```